# Speeding up the drawing of rotated and scaled images in OpenGL

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, transform

I am experimenting with several ways to draw a lot of sprites (e.g. for particle system) and I have some inconclusive results. So this is what I tried and what I have:
This is done drawing 25k sprites:

1. Using regular `glBegin`/`glEnd` and using trig to calculate vertex points - 17-18fps.
2. Using regular `glBegin`/`glEnd`, but using `glRotate`, `glTranslate` and `glScale` to transform the sprite - 14-15fps.
3. Using vertex arrays instead of `glBegin` and `glEnd`, but still using trig to calculate vertex point position - 10-11fps.
4. Using vertex arrays instead of `glBegin` and `glEnd`, but using `glRotate`, `glTranslate` and `glScale` to transform the sprite - 10-11fps.

So my question is, why is using vertex arrays slower than using `glBegin`/`glEnd` while I have read (here even) that it should be faster?

And why does using your own trigonometry (which in my case is 5 cos, 5 sin, more than 5 divisions, 15 multiplications and about 10 additions/subtractions) is faster than using 5 functions (`glPushMatrix()`, `glTranslated()`, `glRotated()`, `glScaled()`, `glPopMatrix()`). I though they are done on the GPU so it should be much, much *faster*.

I do get more promising results when drawing less sprites. Like when I draw 10k sprites, then vertex arrays can be about 5fps faster, but still inconsistent. Also note than these fps can be increased overall because I have other calculations going on, so I am not really looking at the fps itself, but the difference between them. Like if vertex arrays and gl transform was 5-10fps more than `glBegin`/`glEnd` with manual trig, then I would be happy, but for now, it just doesn't seem to be worth the hassle. They would help with porting to GLES (as it doesn't have `glBegin`/`glEnd`), but I guess I will make a separate implementation for that.

So is there any way to speed this up without using geometry shaders? I don't really understand them (maybe some great tutorial?), and they could break compatibility with older hardware, so I want to squeeze all the juice I can without using shaders.

Comment: That seems really low.  CPU/GPU specs?

Answer (score 3):

> So my questions are why does using vertex arrays is slower than using glBegin/glEnd while I have read (here even) that it should be faster?

Who says that they *are* slower?

All you can say is that, for your particular hardware, for your current driver, glBegin/glEnd are slower. Have you verified this on other hardware?

More importantly, there is the question of *how* you are drawing these. Do you draw a single sprite from the vertex array, then draw another, then draw another? Or do you draw *all* of them with a single `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` call?

If you're not drawing all of them in one go (or at least large groups of them at once), then you're not going as fast as you should be.

> And why does using your own trigonometry (which in my case is 5 cos, 5 sin, more than 5 divisions, 15 multiplications and about 10 additions/subtractions) is faster than using 5 functions (glPushMatrix(), glTranslated(), glRotated(), glScaled(), glPopMatrix()). I though they are done on the GPU so it should be A LOT faster.

Well, let's think about this. `glPushMatrix` costs nothing. `glTranslated` creates a double-precision floating-point matrix and then *does a matrix multiply*. `glRotated` does at least one sin and one cos, does some additions and subtractions to compute a matrix (all in double-precision) and then *does a matrix multiply*. `glScaled` computes a matix, and *does a matrix multiply*.

Each "does a matrix multiply" consists of 16 floating-point multiplies and 12 floating-point adds. And since you asked for double-precision math, you can forget about SSE vector math or whatever; this is doing standard math. And you're doing 3 of these *for every point*.

What happens on the GPU is the multiplication of that matrix with the vertex positions. And since you're only passing 4 positions before changing the matrix, it's not particularly surprising that this is slower.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. I don't really have a way to draw all of them at once using one glDrawArray, though I could maybe somehow improve that.
Also thanks for explaining on how translations works. So if I put more vertexes in the array they should be faster? You said "for every point", thus it seems that there shouldn't be a speed gain when I do this on every sprite individually or on the group.

Also, I said glBegin/glEnd is faster, not slower.

Comment: I think I should point out explicitly what @Nicol Bolas didn't state in verbatim bit implied by the last paragraph: glRotate, glTranslate, glScale are executed on the CPU, only the resulting matrix is transferred to the GPU.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf. That explains a lot. Also, is it possible to use one texture coordinates for all quads I drawin vertexarray? I am benchmarking now what Nicol suggested, and I try to draw n number of sprites by populating a vertex array. I just don't want to do the same with texcoord array as it should just be:
 GLfloat texCoords[] = {0.0, 0.0, tbx, 0.0, tbx, tby, 0.0, tby }; And then reused for all drawn sprites. I tried setting "stride" to -sizeof(GLfloat)*4 in hopes that it will advance trough the coords, then go 4 coords back, and then do it again, but that sadly doesn't work.

Comment: @Harry: Negative strides aren't allowed; `GLsizei`, the type of the stride parameter, is an unsigned integer. So you have to provide a texture coordinate for each position.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas - That seems like a waste of space. But ok. Now I tested it and it works, but I guess the negative side is that I can't have more than 32k vertexes? Those are 4k sprites. Because then my app freezes. Also, animating and moving them could be a bigger challenge, but I guess I can modify them in the array.

The good news is that I can draw the same vertex array more than once, so I can benchmark it. For now I can draw 20k sprites without any real fps drop (~70, which is max for me because of vsync).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using glPoints...() instead?  This is kinda what they were designed to do, depending on which version of OpenGL you are supporting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried VBO's instead? They're the current standard, so most cards are optimized in their favor.

Also:

- you should use your own math calculations
- consider offloading as much calculation as possible to a shader

The fps amounts you posted are contrary to what one might expect -- you probably do something wrong. Can you paste some of your rendering code?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking of VBO's too. They would be fast for static sprites (because you just draw on the texture and that's it), but if I animate every sprite then I end up drawing them in some way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific reason to use double precision matrix functions? They are usually a lot slower than single precision ones.

Comment: I tried floating precision matrix functions, but they don't seem to change the speed much (or at all). Probably because it doesn't matter that much in the grand scheme of all things. Drawing the images themselves are the slow part for now. But thanks for telling me this. :) I don't need double precision anyway, so I changed all of them to float.